# Android device is not found in Device Manager (Windows 10 - HP Laptop, Android 8 - Motorolla)

Tags: android, mobile, appium, adb, device-manager

I am new to the mobile world. Hence this question may sound silly to the seasoned professions. Please excuse.

I am trying to connect my mobile device to my laptop. I intention is to do some testing using appium. However I am blocked.

My mobile device (motorola - Android 8) is set to developer mode and is connected to my PC using a USB cable.

When I look for 'adb devices' my mobile phone is not listed.( it doesn't throw an error. It just says 'list of devices attached' but there are no items in the list.

I could not find my android phone in the device manager also. Why is it not displayed ? Am I missing something here ?

Please can someone advise.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you need to verify. Debug mode should be on and make sure to select transfer file and not charging is selected in the device options(swipe down from the top of the screen after plugging your usb cord from the device to your windows machine).